# SSIS - Import Object name is not valid. The name cannot be empty

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to import an SSIS package, however keep getting the following error message:

> The object name is not valid. The name cannot be empty.

Here is the full technical message:

> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String
>   fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String
>   fileName, IDTSEvents events)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageProtectionUtils.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(String
>   password, IDTSEvents events)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageProtectionUtils.LoadPackageWithPassword(PackageLoader
>   loader, IWin32Window dialogParent, String packageName, Boolean
>   askOptionalPassword, String& packagePassword,
>   DtsProtectionEventListener errorListener)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageProtectionUtils.LoadPackageFromFile(String
>   file, IWin32Window dialogParent, Boolean askOptionalPassword,
>   PackageUpgradeOptions packageUpgradeOptions, String& packagePassword,
>   DtsProtectionEventListener errorListener)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageLocationControl.LoadPackage(DtsProtectionEventListener
>   errorListener, PackageUpgradeOptions packageUpgradeOptions, String&
>   packagePassword)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageLocationControl.LoadPackage(DtsProtectionEventListener
>   errorListener, String& packagePassword)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.ObjectExplorerUI.ImportPackageAsAction.ImportPackage(ImportPackageAsForm
>   dlg)

I am not sure why I am getting this message. I have imported other packages several times without any issues.

SQL Server: 2008
SSIS was created in VS 2008

The file name or path has no dots or any other special characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem, I'll post the solution for us.

I was having the same problem on one of our partners servers. We only had SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSIS installed.

We resolved the problem by installing BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio). I was then able to import the packages.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems its related to my machine. I was able to import the same packages from a different workstation.